# Three Unit tests pass when run separately, only one passes when run together

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, specflow

I have three tests, [FunnyCarSteps.cs](http://pastebin.com/3hUSyxCe), [CarLotMaxSteps.cs](http://pastebin.com/QnQEYDE0), and [CarTypeSteps.cs](http://pastebin.com/jFUzbj5w). When run seperatley they all pass, but when run together only CarLotMaxSteps passes.

CarTypeSteps.cs fails at line 49 with a lambda method no source available error.
FunnyCarSteps.cs fails at line 19 with an index out of range error.

I am new to unit testing and don't understand what is going on.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not possible without a look on your Program() class implementation. It seems, that you have static shared data between your instances

Comment: In the **Given**IHaveAFullCarlot method of the `CarLotMaxSteps` class you call `carLotMaxProgram.CarList.Clear();`. Is there any reason for that? The necessity to do some clean up at the beginning of a test is the indication of the dependencies between tests.

Comment: That was the problem mrAtari! Thank You.

Comment: Sergey that was an artifact from when I was experimenting with SesscionContext variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `Program.Main` is `static`, your `CarList` is probably also static. NUnit runs tests in parallel, so each of the tests is running at nearly the same time and each is clearing the list and adding to it at the same time.

That is why your tests run fine on their own, but fail when run together. One starts up and starts testing, then the second comes along and changes the data that the first test is working with.

You need to remove static from everything in `Program` except for main. Ideally, you should refactor all of your car list code out to a new non-static class. Program is for running your program, it shouldn't have anything to do with cars. You should be creating your CarLot (or whatever) class in Main and executing it, not adding properties to Program.

Another option is to add the attribute `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.None)]` to each of your test classes. This will cause them to run one at a time. This will fix the problem with your tests, but it does not fix the fact that your code is incorrect for anything more than a simple exercise.

Comment: Wow! You were absolutely correct. I had the following static class in my program. http://pastebin.com/pquTVmu4 I changed them from static to instance variables and they all started running sucessfully. 

Thank You so much Mr. Prouse!!

Comment: Anthing called GlobalVariables should be immediately suspicious ;)

Comment: Of course, NUnit doesn't run tests in parallel by default - you have to tell it to do so. But a shared static can  cause a problem in any case.